# Why do only IPv6 autoconf services get listed from wlan

Tags: networking, avahi

I've installed squid-deb-proxy on a server which is connected to my router's LAN.

If I browse available zeroconf services from my laptop connected directly to the LAN, I see both IP4 and IP6 squid-deb-proxy advertised:

```
$ avahi-browse -a
...
+   eth0 IPv6 Squid deb proxy on mythbox                    _apt_proxy._tcp      local
+   eth0 IPv4 Squid deb proxy on mythbox                    _apt_proxy._tcp      local
```

But if I disconnect my laptop and try again via the WLAN, I only see the IPv6 service:

```
$ avahi-browse -a
...
+  wlan0 IPv6 Squid deb proxy on mythbox                    _apt_proxy._tcp      local
```

I can still ping the IP4 address without problems, it seems to just be the mdns? Also, the server (on the LAN) can see all the IP4 mdns entries for the other (WLAN) machines. Why do I only see the IPv6 services from the wlan?

Answer (score 0):

I found this happening when I had an iptables firewall blocking UDP port 5353 on my laptop. This blocked the incoming mDNS registration broadcasts for IPv4 addresses, which are normally only carried over IPv4, from reaching my `avahi-daemon` and being registered in the cache.

I had not configured `ip6tables`, so the IPv6 packets carrying IPv6 addresses were not being blocked, and were arriving at the `avahi-daemon` and being stored in the cache. So I could see those in my cache, but not the IPv4 addesses.